# Facebook Marketing API Application review in private network

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-ads-api

Is it possible to submit a Facebook application for a review (Marketing API application) which works only in company's private network?

VPN access would be provided for a FB reviewer.

Comment: you can send a video about it to review.

Comment: Hi luschn, 

Do you mean a video about how to use the app via VPN or the video how the app is actually working (like a demo)?

I find it hard to believe FB review would just accept the video without actually running the app itself.

Comment: yes, that is exactly what i mean. why not just try?

Comment: although, what is the use case? how do you want to use facebook stuff in a pirvate network?

Comment: It's a marketing application for internal purpose, which uses only BM system user for creation and managing of campaigns. It doesn't require FB login.